# Dumb login for OAuth2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I just want a dumb login page for a remote OAuth2-compliant server with password challenge.  This OAuth2 server is really an ancient ASP.Net Identity server and upgrading is not an option so we think the best thing is to treat it like generic OAuth2.

This should be one of the most common setups.  So simple a caveman could do it; but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is how we were doing it before in our local application with .Net Framework

```
private string RetrieveOAuthToken(string username, string password)
{
    var Uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomJwtFormatIssuer"] + "/oauth2/token";
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"];
    var parameters = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&client_id=" + clientId;

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Proxy = null;
        var response = wc.UploadString(Uri, parameters);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(response);
        return result.AccessToken;
```

but now we want to take the login out of app and make a centralized one for all our apps.  We also want to use opaque tokens from now on, so we just want a standard password flow.  Sorta like if you wanted to sign into some app with Google, but you weren't logged in with Google, yet, you would be redirected to a Google login page popup.

Theoretically we could just set the action in the form and let the OAuth2 server handle the.

```
<form action="https://someserver/oauth2/token?grant_type=password" method="get">
  <input name="username"/>
  <input name="password"/>
  <input name="redirecUri" value="https://appserver/receivetoken" type="hidden">
```

but we were hoping that we could still do it through a back channel and conceal the location of the identity server.

What we've tried:

Various configurations like

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth("gwsso", "Single Sign-On", options =>
{
    options.ClientSecret = "someseceit";
    options.ClientId = "someclientid";
    options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://identity.someserver.net";
    options.CallbackPath = "/api/authentication/ExternalLoginBack";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://identity.someserver.net/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://idenitity.someserver.net/oauth2/token"; 
});
```

but that just makes a "Single Sign-on" button which is not what we want and obviously fails gloriously.  We want the Login form to do the heavy lifting.

Green good.  Red bad.
[image]